# Using BASIC Authentication without a Deployment Descriptor

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, basic-authentication

Is it possible to use BASIC authentication without a deployment descriptor (web.xml)?
I have constructed my server using the `@WebServlet` annotation and have used `@ServletSecurity` in order to change the accessibility of my servlets, but I want one of my servlets to only be accessible using a username-password combination.
 I looked over the internet and all I have seen is using `web.xml`, is there a way to do it without `web.xml`, but rather with an annotation, or something of the sort? I am using Tomcat 8.5.9 with Gradle and IntelliJ.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used (@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization) annotation to read the basic auth credentials and used BASE64Decoder to get the username and password for validation.

https://www.java2novice.com/restful-web-services/http-basic-authentication/